# Search in list current setting Vim

Tags: vim

I want to show a list of current settings in Vim with this command: `:set all`. Then all options show but I can't search anything within it (I already trying to use `/`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>). Is there any idea? Thanks.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8379/205 then search in the buffer